# Intent Filter for app in share menu - only show if LOCAL files are shared

Tags: android, android-activity, share, intentfilter

I want my app to only show up in the share menu if local available files are shared.

Currently it looks like following, but this shows my app whenever images are shared, no matter if the are from a internal content provider or if paths to real files on the file system are shared.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.ViewerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name_sharing_to_display"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeFullScreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I'm receiving the local path like following and I save them in a history, I don't want nor need other files.

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI)
{
    String result = null;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
    {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    }
    else
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        if (idx >= 0)
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That `getRealPathFromURI()` will not work even for "local files" on >500 million devices, running Android 4.4 and higher.

First, you may not get `Uri` values from `MediaStore`, as there are other `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementations available for Android (e.g., Google Drive, Dropbox), and their contents are not necessarily in `MediaStore`.

Second, `MediaStore` does not have to support the `DATA` column as holding some local filesystem path.

Third, the file may still be inaccessible, if it is on removable storage, for which you have no access. If you are not going to support `content://` `Uri` values using a `ContentResolver`, your app will not be useful to many people.

That being said, you are welcome to add a `<data>` element to limit your `<intent-filter>` to only `file` schemes.

Comment: Actually it's working on my android 5.0 device... nevertheless, I explain my use case: I have a app you can share pictures with from ANY picture app. My app shows these shows containing the selected pictures and saves them to a database so that the same show can be reshown at any time. Of course, only if the local file still exists. How should I do that than? Content Uri support is no problem, but will those Uris be valid as long as the local file exists?

Comment: Adding data filter does not work for me... tried with file and content as posted in an answer of you in another question.... if I add either of them my app does not show up in the share menu anymore...

Comment: @prom85: "How should I do that than?" -- either copy the image into your app or use the Storage Access Framework and `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver`. `Uri` values do not have to be durable (though they sometimes are) and your access to them does not have to be durable (that is what `takePersistableUriPermission()` is for). "Of course, only if the local file still exists" -- the decision of whether the "local file still exists" is up to the provider. Google Drive, for example, may use an LRU algorithm to minimize disk space.

Comment: @prom85: "if I add either of them my app does not show up in the share menu anymore" -- ah, I had not noticed that you are using `ACTION_SEND`. `ACTION_VIEW` would work with the scheme. With `ACTION_SEND`, your only practical option is to copy the file locally to your app, as there is no requirement that the sender actually maintain that data for very long.

Comment: TakePersistableUriPermission sounds like the thing I need, so that I don't have to know the local path  (although I would like to show the path, but that is not that important for my app). I will try your tips. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ps: if I use TakePersistableUriPermission I don't have to care about if it's a local file or not, don't I? The file will be available as long as? Who will decide when this temporary file for example will be deleted? Probably it's available as long as the apps cache is not manually cleared because my app is using the TakePersistableUriPermission?

Comment: @prom85: "The file will be available as long as?" -- the content pointed to by the `Uri` should be accessible to you, assuming that the `Uri` is still valid. If the user deletes the photo, for example, the fact that you held a persistable permission does not change anything. The Storage Access Framework documentation has guidance for how to check the validity of a persisted `Uri`. Note, though, that the Storage Access Framework is *not* `ACTION_SEND`, and so `takePersistableUriPermission()` may not be available to you.

Comment: PS: there is a way to get the local file path for the Storage Access Framework as well it seems, like here: https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java (`public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)` it seems... But I'll check `takePersistableUriPermission` before...

Comment: @prom85: No, only using undocumented stuff for a few providers. That won't handle Google Drive, Dropbox, or any other third-party provider. And, Google may well lock down arbitrary access to some of those providers, since they're not part of the SDK.

Comment: Actually, I just need local files anyway... But I understand what you mean and will try to do it with ' takePersistableUriPermission'

Comment: `ACTION_VIEW` with only `<data android:mimeType="image/*"/>` already keeps my app from showing in the share menu...

Comment: @prom85: That's because share menus are for `ACTION_SEND` usually.